# Auto Filtro VBA - excel

Tags: vba

Preciso fazer um filtro com um determinado valor em uma aba de uma planilha,depois do filtro feito, preciso copiar, abrir um novo documento, e colar essa informção.

Desenvolvi o código abaixo mas não está dando certo.

segue o código

```
Sub filtrar()

Worksheets(Array("Planilha3", "Planilha2", "Planilha3",)).Copy

ActiveSheet.Range("Planilha3").AutoFilter Field:=Range("E1:E1048576").Column, Criteria1:="Cell 01"


With ActiveWorkbook

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close



End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Você usa a Planilha3 duas vezes e possui uma vígula no fim. Portanto a função espera 4 Planilhas. `Worksheets(Array("Planilha3", "Planilha2", "Planilha3",)).Copy`. O correto seria `Worksheets(Array("Planilha1", "Planilha2", "Planilha3")).Copy`

Comment: @danieltakeshi obrigado pela observação, mas errei na hora de digitar

Comment: o Erro apresentado é :

Erro em tempo de execução 1004

Erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definicao de objeto

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro? E creio que `ActiveSheet.Range("Planilha3").AutoFilter` está errado. Você quer filtrar somente a coluna 3 da Planilha3 nova para o dado `="Cell 01"`?

Comment: O erro ocorre na linha ActiveSheet.Range("Planilha3").AutoFilter Field:=Range("E1:E1048576").Column, Criteria1:="Cell 01"

Comment: e sobre o filtro é isso mesmo, quero buscar na aba ( planilha 3) na coluna 3 o dado = "cell 01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Código

```
Sub filtrar()
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim UltimaLinhaE As Long
    Worksheets(Array("Planilha1", "Planilha2", "Planilha3")).Copy
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha3")
    With ws3
        'Limpa os Autofiltros da Planilha para evitar erros
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
        'Última Linhada colunaE
        UltimaLinhaE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        'Autofiltro
        .Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Cell 01"
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

## Explicação

O [Método Autofiltro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) estava sendo usado incorretamente.

O método é `Range.Autofilter`, portanto uma range precisa ser inserida.

Deste modo: `.Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE)`

> Obs.: A variável `fname1` não está sendo especificada neste código. E se o que deseja é filtrar antes de enviar para o novo arquivo Excel, usar `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` e criar uma nova planilha temporária para ser copiada ao novo arquivo.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, porem o filtro esta sendo feito na coluna a , onde mudo para filtrar a coluna e ?

Comment: Como você está utilizando o Range? `.Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Cell 01"` Pois se estão descritas todas as colunas da planilha, mudar o campo Field para `Field:=5`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado @danieltakeshi