# Classificar Planilha por algo ao clicar em "explorar"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, planilha, microsoft-office

Boa Tarde pessoal,

Estou tentando filtrar uma planilha especifica. A ideia consiste em filtrar uma planilha por um assunto. Ao clicar em Explorar.

Exemplo "Planilha a ser filtrada automaticamente"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei um ID na coluna tipo tentar facilitar a classificação automática, "estou pensando como se fosse uma querye não sei se existe alternativa melhor no excel"

Eu teria então uma outra sheet com a seguinte tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa tabela representa em ordem crescente os ID's [1,2,3,4] quando eu clica-se por em "details" do tipo brigadeiro, ele me levaria automaticamente para a tabela principal já filtrada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não consegui construir uma formula pra isso, estou aberto a sugestões.

Comment: Não entendi a necessidade. Não seria mais simples filtrar por "Tipo" e em seguida filtrar "Brigadeiro"?

Comment: Por exemplo ao clicar em Details de Chocolates, ele iria filtrar a outra tabela pelo código 1 que representa todos os bolos de Chocolate

Comment: Utilize o [AutoFiltro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300962/75104) com o VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Entendo que a solução tem duas necessidades

- Seleção do tipo de bolo
- Filtro do tipo de bolo selecionado

Em relação a isto, ataquei o ponto 2. Minha proposta é de um filtro avançado.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FiltroAvançado()

    Dim rngBase As Range
    Dim rngCriterios As Range
    
    Set rngBase = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngCriterios = Range("e1:g2")
       
    rngBase.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rngCriterios


End Sub
```

O que for inserido em E2, F2 ou G2 será utilizado como critério para o filtro. Não consegui um conclusão em atender ao ponto 1.

[image: Planilha]